# Вывод одномерного массива в C++

Tags: c++

Программой задаётся одномерный массив, числа которого генерируются произвольно,
нужно организовать его вывод с помощью cout. Но при таком выводе:

```
cout < < m[i]; //без пробелов
```

Вывод числе происходит без пробелов, т.е. сплошные цыфры

```
54216452122454235412
```

Как сделать такой вывод

```
54 21 64 52 12 24 54 23 54 12
```

printf - не подходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так:

```
cout << m[i] << ' ';
```

> printf -не подходит

Почему? Нельзя им пользоваться или ты сам такой вывод сделал? А то можно так:

```
printf("%i ", m[i]);
```

Comment: через printf преподу не нарв) сказал типо мы такого учили,делай как учили)

Comment: спасибо всё работает

Comment: В реальном программировании форматированный вывод через printf() делать проще. Когда все преподу сдадите, сообщите ему об этом, пусть правильно учит.

Comment: @toris, где Вы учитесь? Где такие "умные" преподы водятся?

Comment: Сишный printf не типобезопасен, поэтому правильно учит. Кстати, я изобрёл свой типобезопасный String::Format. Используется так:

int iv=123;
double pi=3.1415926;
String str=String::Format("iv=<^>; pi=<^>")(iv)(pi);

 Такое вот форматирование строк при помощи смайликов.

Comment: Программист С++ должен знать и printf, и scanf, поскольку они реально применяются и масса кода написана с ними. А по поводу типобезопасности,так на этот случай прогеру и голова дана, чтобы ошибки не допускать. Кроме того, компиляторы сразу выдают предупреждения при несоответствии типов.

Comment: >Программист С++ должен знать и printf, и scanf, поскольку они реально применяются и масса кода написана с ними.
 Знать должен, но использовать нежелательно.

>А по поводу типобезопасности, так на этот случай прогеру и голова дана, чтобы ошибки не допускать.

 Любой человек может допустить ошибку, даже если он знает, как правильно надо делать. Он может написать правильно, а потом заменить тип с int на float, а про то, что где-то он передаёт эту переменную в printf и не вспомнить. Надо отлавливать ошибки во время компиляции.

Comment: >Кроме того, компиляторы сразу выдают предупреждения при несоответствии типов.

 Не знаю, как на других компиляторах, а у меня Visual Studio на четвёртом уровне предупреждений не выдаёт никаких предупреждений по printf\scanf.

Comment: в gcc все очень четко пишется даже без -Wall

Comment: не надо использовать сишные функции в C++, это дурной тон и чревато ошибками. Используйте или стандартную библиотеку и << или http://fmtlib.net. Гоните из своих проектов все вот это чудовищное наследие старых веков.

Comment: @strangeqargo проблема в том, что синтаксис printf/scanf намного удобнее, чем std::cout  и cin... в частности, сложности, когда необходимо вывести double с определенным precision, а потом вернуть настройки по умолчанию. Со stream'ами это все решаемо, но код получается монструозный ((((

Answer (score 5):

например

```
cout << m[i] << "  " ;
```

Comment: Не успел это написать.

Comment: А зачем 2 пробела?

Comment: не знаю, чтобы мало не показалось :)

Comment: -зачем ты два раза jmp smth поставил??  
-а вдруг первый не сработает...

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

...

copy(m, m + sizeof(m)/sizeof(m[0]), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Не для новичков конечно, но поставлю '+'.

`m + sizeof(m)/sizeof(m[0])`

 Если не ошибаюсь, это можно заменить на end(m).

Comment: `endl` не рекомендуется использовать, лучше - и быстрее - "\n". `endl`, как бы это сказать, *флашит буферы аутпута*

Answer (score 2):

Подключаем библиотеку

```
#include<iomanip>
```

далее при выводе массива:

```
cout<<m[i]<<setw(5);
```

Функция `setw` делает пробелы между элементами на количество единиц, указанных в скобках.

Comment: setw задает ширину поля вывода (данные + заполнитель), а не 'делает пробелы'. Заполнитель задается через setfill. И задавать ширину все же стоит ПЕРЕД выводом данных, а не после.

Answer (score 1):

```
 cout << m[0];
 for(int i=1; i < sizeof m/sizeof(int);) cout << ' ' << m[i++];
 cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
usin namespace std;
int main(){
int a[1024];
for(int i=0; i<=1024; i++)
a[i]=i;
for(int i=0; i<=1024; i++)
cout << a[i] << ' ';//ну или printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Зачем отвечать, если такой ответ уже есть? Тем более, что у тебя ошибка - выход за пределы массива. Так как отсчёт идёт с нуля, послений элемент - 1023, а ты включаешь 1024 в цикл.

Comment: я не нашел полного ответа.  
тем более, что ошибка не фатальна и её можно исправить даже, если ты начинающий

Comment: насчет нефатальной ошибки, это вы зря. подобный выход за пределы массива может привести к повреждению данных, к нарушению безопасности и просто к аварийной выгрузке пограммы.

Comment: > и просто к аварийной выгрузке пограммы.

 Вряд ли. На стеке, по-моему, ошибки переполнения буфера не проверяются, поэтому вылет бует только при использовании программой повреждённых данных.

>я не нашел полного ответа.

 Заполнить массив он и сам смог, раз задал вопрос по его выводу. Цикл он тоже объявил судя по тому, что показал результат вывода своей программы без пробелов.
>её можно исправить даже, если ты начинающий

 Когда я был начинающим, я натыкался на такие ошибки. Компилятор о них не сообщает. Только в Visual Studio можно включить анализ кода, при котором он напишет об этой ошибке

Comment: Возьмем эльфа. Положим, функция main. Первая переменная, что в ней декларируется, это массив. В ходе выполнения программы выделяется место в стеке с помощью изменения содержимого регистра esp. Положим, мы переполнили массив при заполнении. Что лежит за массивом перед доступным функции стеком? char ** argv. Если мы его нарушим, то при попытке прочитать параметры вызова процесса, наступит segmentation fault. Это лишь один из сценариев.